# R: Extracting nth number occurring in a string

Tags: r

I have a R data frame called `df`, and in the 1st row and the 2nd column of `df`, I have the following `string` entry:

```
 df[1,2]="[127512, 27455, 70464, 257686, 127094, 225910, 225910, 257686, 257686, 257686, 
 127094, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 1936, 1936, 1936, 1936, 1936, 1936, 78336, 127512, 
 27455, 70464, 257686, 127094, 225910, 225910, 257686, 257686, 257686, 127094, 10000, 
 10000, 10000, 10000, 1936, 1936, 1936, 1936, 1936, 1936, 78336]"
```

how can I extract, say, 4th number in this string (which in our case 257686)?
I am not so good with regexp....thank you.

Comment: A better question may be why you're not storing this as a list rather than a data.frame.

Comment: it's just the way my raw excel file is structured....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something unsatisfactory about Ananta's solution:

1. it contains a space (which can be fixed if you make the split pattern `", "`), but more importantly
2. it wouldn't work if instead of the fourth item you had asked for the first one. The answer would include the leading `[` character.

Since your data string is valid JSON, I would do:

```
library(rjson)
fromJSON(df[1, 2])[4]
```

which would also work at extracting the first item.

Answer (score 3):

missed `[[1]]` in first draft, so edited with suggestion from @thelatemail

```
strsplit(df[1,2],",", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][4]
```

as flodel comments below, be careful with how you handle the first and last element. quick fix may be replacing `"["` with `""` which does not need third party library

Comment: lol, just typing answer out of fly without checking. Thanks for correcting me

Comment: yes, as flodel comments below, be careful with how you handle the first and last element.